# How to match string starting with specific charachter in regex

Tags: regex

How to detect string like this :

```
date-2014_10_3/
```

and

```
date-2014103/
```

Comment: What language are we talking about? Or just regular expressions in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this,

```
date-\d{4}_?\d{1,2}_?\d{1,2}\/
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jK3tX3/4)

But it won't check for month or date or year.

Comment: it won't check for month or date or year.

Comment: tanx a lot  Avinash Raj

Comment: and how to detect string that start with "date-" and after use any integer and the last ended with / charachter for ex: attr-95000/ or attr-59-62/

Comment: in the above there is no date string.

Comment: yes i need this regex for any attributs that use above stractur, date was one of attribute

Comment: yes but i need detect both of them , in fact not important type of charachter after attr-

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56871/discussion-between-a-4j4vv1-and-avinash-raj).